# Angular NGX-SOAP Request Gets ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_TRUNCATED

Tags: angular, soap, http-headers, wsdl

I'm currently in localhost, and trying to make soap request to an external public SOAP service. I was able to make requests on PHP localhost with a Soap client. But now I'm having problems on Angular while making requests. Let me introduce my code.

First of all WSDL's online version => [HERE](https://api.n11.com/ws/CityService.wsdl)

Module's constructor has no error:

```
  constructor(private soap: NgxSoapService, private httpClient: HttpClient, private snackBar: MatSnackBar, public dialog: MatDialog, private auth: AuthenticationService, private restApi: RestApi) {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'text/xml',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'origin, content-type, accept, authorization',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST',
    });
    this.soap.createClient('./assets/wsdl/CityService.wsdl', {headers: headers}).then(client => {
      this.client = client;
    })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

This is a basic SOAP request function.

```
  makeAnExampleRequest() {
    this.client.call('GetCities', {}).subscribe((res: ISoapMethodResponse) => console.log(res), (error) => console.error(error));
  }
```

When above function is called, I get following error:

From console.error(error):

```
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "https://api.n11.com/ws/cityService/", ok: false, …}
headers: HttpHeaders
normalizedNames: Map(0) {}
lazyUpdate: null
headers: Map(0) {}
__proto__: Object
status: 0
statusText: "Unknown Error"
url: "https://api.n11.com/ws/cityService/"
ok: false
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
message: "Http failure response for https://api.n11.com/ws/cityService/: 0 Unknown Error"
error: ProgressEvent
isTrusted: true
lengthComputable: false
loaded: 0
total: 0
type: "error"
target: XMLHttpRequest {__zone_symbol__xhrSync: false, __zone_symbol__xhrURL: "https://api.n11.com/ws/cityService/", __zone_symbol__loadfalse: Array(1), __zone_symbol__errorfalse: null, __zone_symbol__xhrScheduled: true, …}
currentTarget: XMLHttpRequest {__zone_symbol__xhrSync: false, __zone_symbol__xhrURL: "https://api.n11.com/ws/cityService/", __zone_symbol__loadfalse: Array(1), __zone_symbol__errorfalse: null, __zone_symbol__xhrScheduled: true, …}
eventPhase: 0
bubbles: false
cancelable: false
defaultPrevented: false
composed: false
timeStamp: 3544.754999995348
srcElement: XMLHttpRequest {__zone_symbol__xhrSync: false, __zone_symbol__xhrURL: "https://api.n11.com/ws/cityService/", __zone_symbol__loadfalse: Array(1), __zone_symbol__errorfalse: null, __zone_symbol__xhrScheduled: true, …}
returnValue: true
cancelBubble: false
path: []
__proto__: ProgressEvent
__proto__: HttpResponseBase
```

From zone-evergreen.js:

```
POST https://api.n11.com/ws/cityService/ net::ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_TRUNCATED
```

I tried another WSDL's with another requests that need auth object and all I get is the same error

Comment: Did you solved this issue ?

Comment: I came up with writing a backend to make wsdl queries.

Comment: Can you share the backend code? It will be very useful for me.